# entity framework one to one fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship, one-to-one

Is there a way to configure one to one relationship, only using Fluent API? (No Data Annotations).

I need something like this:

```
public class User
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Address
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Address {get;set;}
   public User User {get;set;}
   public int UserId {get;set;}
}
```

Address has a identity Id but also a Foreign Key to User (UserId). Is it possible?

Comment: If `Address` has a separate FK to `User` it's always a 1:n association as I explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27381980/861716). You'd have to enforce 1:1 in code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this for your User/Address case should work:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
                    .HasKey(e => e.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
                    .Property(e => e.UserId)
                    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
                    .HasRequired(e => e.User)
                    .WithRequiredDependent(s => s.Address);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   }
```

For more details about Entity Framework Fluent API, you can refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj591620.aspx) or [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) .

If you already have a database and you want to generate POCOs for it, you can use a tool like [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838)

Hope that helps.

Comment: What I need is Id as PK and identity and UserId as foreign key. I still believe it's not possible.

Comment: Is there a way to create it without property in Principal class? In this sample User hasn't Address property.